# Should I set a maximum sell limit per transaction/24 hours on a Bep20 token?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, binance, binance-smart-chain

I'm creating a token and want to solve the big whale issue of pump and dump, or just the dump problem. As such, I thought about limiting how much an address can sell per transaction or per 24 hours.

Is this possible in a Bep20 smart contract? My coder tells me it's not. If it is, does this also automatically affect the amount a person can buy?

Would there be unknown negative consequences of this type of restriction?

Would you buy this type of token?

Lastly, Are there any BEP20 (or other blockchain) tokens currently implementing this?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to limit how many tokens can an address receive during a time period.

```
struct TransferHistory {
    uint32 transferTime;
    address from;
    address to;
    uint256 amount;
}

mapping (address => TransferHistory[]) transferHistoryPerReceiver;

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool) {
    require(receivedDuringPast24Hours(_to) <= 100, 'You can only receive up to 100 tokens during the past 24 hours');
}

function receivedDuringPast24Hours(address _who) external view returns (uint256) {
    // todo loop through `transferHistoryPerReceiver[_who]`
    // filter and return sum based on the time period
}
```

Decentralized exchanges (such as PancakeSwap) hold the tokens in their Pair contracts (e.g. YourToken/CAKE is one pair contract, YourToken/WBNB is another pair contract, ...). You can limit the transfer based on the `msg.sender` (which would be the pair contract).

```
if (msg.sender == pancakeswapPairAddress) {
    require(receivedDuringPast24Hours(_to) <= 100, 'You can only receive up to 100 tokens during the past 24 hours');
}
```

However, one person can have practically unlimited amount of addresses. So unless you perform some KYC process (off-chain) connecting each real person to their address(es), this limit can be easily bypassed.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for confirming it can be done. My coder might just be limited in his skillset. LOL.  I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I did cast. Do you know if pancakeswap has a limit on buys. If I create a liquidity pool, will someone be able to buy the whole lot at once?

Comment: There's currently no hard limit - except for the limit of how much assets are in the actual liquidity pool (can't spend more than there is). And few warnings (and possible need to confirm them before submitting the actual transaction) on the Pancake UI if you are about to submit an order that would significantly change the price or spend a significant portion of the staked assets.

Comment: Thanks. I was planning on spending 1 bnb on the liquidity pool for 30 billion tokens. I see how this could be dangerous.

Comment: @NiftyMcG, thankfully I'm not your coder, pancakeswap limits the price impact to 15% .

Comment: Make sure to delete every item that is older than 24 hours, or else the growing array will increase gas fees endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint256 daysSinceUnixTimestampStarted = ((block.timestamp / secondsPerDay) + 4)
        //user             //day    //counterOperations
mapping(address => mapping(uint256->uint256) operationsPerDay

require(operationsPerDay[msg.sender]++ < limit);
```

should work

sorry for being so late.

Comment: also you can manipulate this formula to do weekly or what ever kind of limitations, or for example fridays only:
((block.timestamp / secondsPerDay) + 4) % 7 == 5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).